# HTTP/SOAP packet size

Tags: sockets, http, soap, packet

I am trying to determine how much network overhead there is for web services. From research I know that UDP has a header size of 24 bytes plus the data. So if I wanted to send the message foo over UDP to listener the packet would be 27 bytes. If I wanted to call a method on a web service and pass it foo how much more data gets added to the packet?

Answer (score 1):

On linux, you could use iftop for that. Suppose your webservice listens on udp port 9999, then following command tells you how many bytes pass over the network:

```
iftop -nN -f "port 9999 and udp"
```

If you're using windows, I guess wireshark could help to do the counting.

Comment: There are a few ways I can count the packet sizes on windows. Not trying to figure out how big the packets are going to be after I build them. Trying to avoid building the tool stack to test it in the first place if the information is available.